# writeImage with imagick in codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, imagick

I'm using codeigniter and imagick for convert pdf to png image file.

```
$im = new imagick();
$im->setResolution ( 110,110);
$im->readImage($target_path);
$num_page = $im->getnumberimages();
for ($i=0; $i < $num_page ; $i++) { 
$im->readImage($target_path."[".$i."]");
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage(?);
}
$im->destroy();
```

I don't know how save this file in `codeignietr_folder/assets/pdf-img`
I tried .`./../assets/test.png` and `localhost/codeignietr_folder/assets/pdf-img`
but it doesn't work!
how could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$im->writeImage($file);`  where

```
$file = getcwd() . '/assets/pdf-img/test.png';
```

Comment: For saving image you need to provide absolute server path where you want to save file. getcwd() just return current working directory, more details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: yup...i just create new account!